# How to get all pages referenced from some Wikipedia page?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am working with Wikipedia API and have a problem of getting referenced pages from the current. For example page [Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington) refers to

1. George Washington (1732–1799), first president of the United States
2. Washington (state), United States
3. Washington, D.C., the capital of the United States
4. Washington (name), including a list of people with the given name or surname Washington

Is any API call that returns this pages?

Answer (score 1):

To get all links from Wikipedia page [Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington) use [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Blinks) :

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&pllimit=500&plnamespace=0&titles=Washington
```